# What is needed for a 512Kb HDMI EDID EEPROM? (re: 512KB IC2 EEPROM)

Tags: i2c, eeprom, hdmi

I'm trying to build an HDMI "dummy" plug that simulates a plugged-in monitor (to trick GPUs into thinking a monitor is plugged in).

Many of these "dummy" adapters exist and are simply an I2C EEPROM connected to the DDC pins.  However, every adapter I've found is only 256 KB (ie. 24C02 chip).

I've tried searching and have found 512 KB chips (ie. 24C04) but they are 256KB x2 instead of one 512KB area.

Are there any 512KB x1 I2C EEPROM chips?

If not, then how is it possible for monitors are other devices to use 384KB and 512KB EDIDs?

Comment: Btw, the 24C02 is a 2 kilobit EEPROM -> 256 **byte**, not 256 **kilo**byte

Comment: Afaik the way the addressing scheme works is that it's not possible to put more than 256 bytes in a single block because you're only sending an 8-bit address to the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your memory sizes are off by a factor of 1000 (or 1024).

You don't need any larger memory than 256 bytes in practice, for two blocks of 128 bytes, so a 24c02 is just right for the job.

And by EDID standard maximum size is 32768 bytes for 256 blocks of 128 bytes but the addressing is not compatible with standard I2C memory chips any more, for any EDID larger than 2 blocks of 128 bytes, you need a special EDID compatible EEPROM which supports selecting more than two blocks using a segment pointer.

Comment: This is the answer.  Thank you!  It looks like the CAT24C208 is the only EEPROM I could find that is compatible with multiple segments and sounds like it's compatible with E-EDID.  Let me know if you can think of any others please.  Thanks again!

Comment: @SofaKng You still don't need a special E-EDID chip that supports multiple segments. No monitor has ever needed to show such large EDIDs, especially, if you only want to make a dummy plug which you can also just buy. And video cards are likely to detect if you just have a monitor connected but it's turned off because data lanes are unterminated.